# PHP -> PDO Update Statement

Tags: php, sql, pdo, sql-update

I was trying to do a SQL query ( `insert into users set cash = cash + 20` ),
can anyone help me with the PDO prepared statement version of the above query?

Comment: This is not a valid insert statement. This should be `insert into users set cash = 20` . Are you looking for update statement?

Comment: @Francois: Oh! Really. Checkout the second syntax of INSERT http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html

Comment: @Shakti Singh - I owe you an apology. You're absolutely correct. I had no idea you could do that.

Comment: @Shakti Singh - I was thinking some more about this and @junjie isn't specifying which database server he's using. You're right that `SET cash = 20` work, in MySQL, but in others, it won't necessarily work. For instance, PostgreSQL doesn't allow that. Because of the name of PDO, it may be best not to use `SET cash = 20` since it's not a standard.

Comment: @Francois: What do you mean by standard? You mean that the things supported by `DATABASE Sever` Then this is a standard `INSERT` statement and according to a survey `95%` users are using `PHP` with `mysql`. May be this user is not in that `95%` but there is more chance he is in that `95%`.

Comment: @Shakti Singh - Why would someone use PDO if it's not to be database agnostic? If you want to use MySQL, why not just use MySQLi instead? And speaking of standards, [SQL92](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL-92), which is a standard, doesn't have have `SET` for `INSERT` statement. **I agree that most PHP developers use MySQL** but I just wanted to clarify that the SQL statement you provided (which is valid in MySQL) **might not work in all other database servers** (i.e. PostgreSQL, Oracle, Sybase, ...).

Comment: @Francois: You are still misunderstanding here, you did not get my point. Hopes you will get it. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I can't really figure out if you're looking to insert or update. Here are PDO prepared statement examples. They assume that you've already connected and that the PDO object is `$dbh`.

**Insert:**

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare('INSERT INTO `users` (`cash`) VALUES (?)');
$sth->execute(array(20));
```

**Update:**

```
// All users
$sth = $dbh->prepare('UPDATE `users` SET `cash` = `cash` + ?');
$sth->execute(array(20));

// A specific user (assuming that there's a field name "id")
$sth = $dbh->prepare('UPDATE `users` SET `cash` = `cash` + ? WHERE `id` = ?');
$sth->execute(array(20, $id));
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to do an update, not an insert

```
 UPDATE users SET cash = (cash + 20)
 WHERE <condition>
```